# Suggestion for jQuery range slider plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

do you guys know range slider plugin like this one:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range

but smaller.

because I don't want to include the whole ui pack just to use the slider thing from it. It's like 150 KB..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just download a custom subset of the UI plugin with the dependencies the slider needs, you'll get a file of about 21kb.

http://jqueryui.com/download

Click "Deselect All" at the top right of the tickbox-list, then tick the first 3 (Core, Widget, Mouse) as well as the Slider itself (under Widgets).